# Mybatis MateObject.setValue("list[0]", 1), list not be created automatically

Tags: mybatis

Use MateObject:setValue("list[0]", 1) to modify the null list, the list object will not be created automatically.

```java
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        MetaObject metaObject = SystemMetaObject.forObject(demo);
        metaObject.setValue("list[0]", 10);
        Assertions.assertEquals(10, demo.getList().get(0));
    }
    public static class Demo {
        private List<Integer> list;

        public List<Integer> getList() {
            return list;
        }

        public void setList(List<Integer> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
    }
```

error:

```
org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: The 'list' property of null is not a List or Array.

    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.BaseWrapper.setCollectionValue(BaseWrapper.java:102)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.BeanWrapper.set(BeanWrapper.java:56)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.setValue(MetaObject.java:139)
```

Using MateObject.setValue("list[0]", 1) to modify the null list, If null, automatically created.

Comment: `SystemMetaObject` is MyBatis' internal utility class and NOT for public use. We cannot stop you from using it, but you should know that its implementation could change in the future without warning.

Comment: thanks! I found this problem when I was reading the source code.

Comment: That probably means MyBatis does not need such functionality.